# How to prove if a set is a field or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

For this question, I'm not sure how to prove whether this set is a field or not. I know that if the set is  a field it needs to fill in all the requirements, like the commutative, associative, and distribution laws, as well as the additive and multiplicative principle, which it looks like it does. I'm not sure how to further prove this. Can anyone please help me out?

Is the set $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{7}] := \{a + b
\sqrt{7}\mid a, b ∈ Q\}$ with addition and multiplication
defined by
$(a + b
\sqrt{7}) ⊕ (c + d
\sqrt{7}) =(a + c) + (b + d)
\sqrt{7}$ for all $a, b, c, d ∈ \mathbb{Q}$,
$(a + b
\sqrt{7} ⊗ (c + d
\sqrt{7}) =(ac + 7bd) + (ad + bc) \sqrt{7}$ for all $a, b, c, d ∈ \mathbb{Q}$,
a field?

Comment: Have you tried checking the commutative and associative etc properties formally? If you've proved all the field axioms work, then you have a proof that your set forms a field.

Comment: Well, check the "requirements", better named *axioms*. For one, identify the neutral element (the zero) and the multiplicative unit (the one) .

Comment: But aren't the commutative and associative properties already demonstrated in the equations? like how do I formally prove it if it's already demonstrated there?

Comment: To prove that these properties hold in general, take two arbitrary elements (for example, $a + b \sqrt{7}$ and $c + d \sqrt{7}$) and show that everything necessary holds for these two arbitrary elements. Commutativity, check $A \cdot C = C \cdot A$, associativity, the existence of identity and inverses...

Comment: I am so confused. Basically we're checking if the left side is equal to the right side?

Comment: You're right that you get commutative, associative and distributive laws free, inherited from the reals. (If you don't have the reals as a container you do need to check them algebraically.) The subtler part is to show that the multiplicative inverse of a nonzero element is in the subset. Hint: rationalize the denominator.

Comment: There is no denominator?

Comment: What is the multiplicative  inverse of $a + b\sqrt{7}$? $1/(a + b\sqrt{7})$ has a denominator. Is that reciprocal in the set you started with?

Comment: Ok, so what about for the additive identity?

Answer (score 1):

These are the ordinary addition and multiplication in $\mathbf C$, and $\mathbf Q\bigl[\sqrt 7\bigr]$ is a subset thereof. So all you have to prove is

1. $\;\mathbf Q\bigl[\sqrt 7\bigr]$ is a subring of  $\mathbf C$, i.e. it is stable by addition and multiplication, and $1\in\mathbf Q\bigl[\sqrt 7\bigr]$.
2. The inverse of a non-zero element $a+b\sqrt 7$ $\;(a,b\in\mathbf Q)$ is an element of $\mathbf Q\bigl[\sqrt 7\bigr]$.